# Calculating percentage/fraction of thematic pixels with coarser resampled pixels in QGIS/GRASS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I am using QGIS 3.4.9 on Mac OS10.13.6.

How can I edit raster data type to change it from thematic to continuous/quantitative?

details:
I am trying to calculate the fractional (percentage) composition of 5-m input pixels at a 30-m output resolution. So, for example, if a given window had 2 pixels of my chosen class for the fine-scale input data, the output of the resampled would be assigned as 0.05555 (2/36). I haven't been able to locate a single tool to do this, so I converted my thematic raster into a series of byte images each assigning 1s to pixels of the given class and zero to everything else (using r.reclass). I then planned to use GDAL warp to resample to 30 m and output the average of each of my thematic categories of interest.

However, I am blocked from this due to the following message:

> Warning: Input file /QGISWork2019v3/Nica2015ShrubScrub.tif has a thematic RAT, which will likely lead to bad results when using a resampling method other than nearest neighbour or mode so we are discarding it.

I understand the basis for this; however I have not been able to find a way to edit the thematic type in the header/metadata. All help searches for topics such as RAT and thematic and raster type, were empty. I suppose a workaround might be to go into rastercalc and multiply by 1.0 (I can try are report back as a comment), but I'd prefer to stay in the 8-bit data type.

Comment: As you have output from r.reclass, I would suggest to use `r.resamp.stats` with `sum` option to aggregate the cell size, instead of GDAL. After that you can divide the resampled layer by 36.

Comment: I tried this and it worked, so this is a good workaround. thanks.